# How do I ignore certain voice channels? discord.py

Tags: discord.py

The code is made to give 1 point every minute. The problem is that in different voice channels, points should not be issued, for example, afk channel.

Tried to do it via if member in guild.afk_channel, but it didn't work: /

```py
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        while True:
            with open("./data/Points.json", "r") as file:
                data = json.load(file)

            for guild in self.bot.guilds:
                if str(guild.id) not in data.keys():
                    data[str(guild.id)] = {}

                voices = [channel for channel in guild.voice_channels]
                members = [channel.members for channel in voices]

                ids = []
                for lst in members:
                    for member in lst:
                        ids.append(member.id)      

                if len(ids) <= 0:
                    continue

                for member in ids:
                    if str(member) not in data[str(guild.id)].keys():
                        data[str(guild.id)][str(member)] = 0

                    elif member in self.prev:
                        data[str(guild.id)][str(member)] += 1

                    else:
                        self.prev.append(member)

            with open("./data/Points.json", "w") as file:
                json.dump(data, file, indent=4)

            await asyncio.sleep(60)
```

Comment: That's a big chunk of code. Which variable holds the list of channels, and which variable holds the list of afk channels? Which line of the code corresponds to "issue 1 point"? Can you maybe add some variation on `if message.channel not in afk_channels:` just before?

Comment: `voices = [channel for channel in guild.voice_channels]` list of channels and

`data[str(guild.id)][str(member)] += 1` Gives 1 point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I'd recommend using a built-in [`task`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html?highlight=task#discord.ext.tasks.Loop) for this, as it's the same function being executed over and over on a set timescheme.

To answer your question:

You could create a list of channel id's (or actual `channel` instances) to ignore, which I'll call `ignored_channels` for the sake of simplicity. Then, you can filter these out of your `voices` list, so that your `for-loop` won't iterate over them, and they will be ignored. You can do so like this:

```
voices = [channel for channel in guild.voice_channels if channel not in ignored_channels]
```

or, if you worked with the other method of id's (which I'd recommend, as it's a fair bit faster & easier to implement):

```
voices = [channel for channel in guild.voice_channels if channel.id not in ignored_channels]
```

This way, the voice channels in `ignored_channels` will not be checked, which is what you were trying to achieve.